# IE11 JavaScript (Error: SCRIPT445) "Object doesn't support this action"

Tags: javascript, youtube, internet-explorer-11

I use a Javascript solution which loads the youtube player API asynchronously.
The whole script is supposed to play the video when scrolled to its position.
It works in all browsers and also in IE(11), but **sometimes** in IE I get an error in Developer Tools: *SCRIPT445 (Object doesn't support this action)*.

The Youtube Player still works but it seems to crash other scripts. I looked around in the web and also here on Stackoverflow. There seem to be others who have similar problems but they were too specific. Maybe someone could help me with this one. Here is the part of the code which makes the problem:

```
var yt_int, yt_players={},
    initYT = function() {
        $(".ytplayer").each(function() {
            yt_players[this.id] = new YT.Player(this.id);    <-- Error line 
        });
    };

$.getScript("//www.youtube.com/player_api", function() {
    yt_int = setInterval(function(){
        if(typeof YT === "object"){
            initYT();
            clearInterval(yt_int);
        }
    },500);
});
```

Comment: Is it possible that the error line is being run before the youtube player script is loaded?

Comment: Sure, very possible ;) I thought yt_int had to be declared before getScript uses it.. So do you mean switching positions of `$.getScript()` and `var yt_int, yt_players={}` would help? I just tried.. seems to work, problem is that its very sporadic (hard to debug)

Comment: Some kind of race condition is the only thing I can think of, maybe try using a setTimeout to offload execution of the init function. Instead of initYT(), setTimeout(initYT, 0).

Comment: So, after 30+ refreshes on 3 different systems `setTimeout(initYT, 0)` really seems to fix it :) Thanks a lot! How can I declare your comment as the correct answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a race condition in IE that is firing off your script loader callback before the entire script is evaluated. By using `setTimeout(initYT, 0)` you will allow the script to finish evaluating before firing your initialization function.

Answer (score 9):

object doesn't support this action is error is coming in IE11 using window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize')); we need to d handle the condition for ie11.

```
 if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE') !== -1 || navigator.appVersion.indexOf('Trident/') > 0) {
                   var evt = document.createEvent('UIEvents');
                   evt.initUIEvent('resize', true, false, window, 0);
                   window.dispatchEvent(evt);
        } else {
                 window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
        }
```

Comment: No longer recommended to use initUIEvent and this throws a Typescript error for me nowadays. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UIEvent/initUIEvent