# Saving file on IE11 with FileSaver

Tags: javascript, file, internet-explorer-11, filesaver.js

I'm using FileSaver library ( https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js) and does not work on IE11, with other browsers I had no problem.

The code is this:

```
var file = new File(["content"], "sample.xml", { type: "application/xml;charset=utf-8" });
saveAs(file);
```

I'm getting this error when the first instruction (new) executes:

> "the object does not accept this action"

There's an open issue on git hub, but actually with no solution, I'm looking for a workaround that should work on IE11, like this:

```
try {
                var file = new File([msg.d], "test.xml", { type: "application/xml;charset=utf-8" });
                saveAs(file);
     } catch (err) {
                // Code that works on IE11 ....
     }
```

Any help should be appreciated.

Comment: have you tried blob instead of file? don't think it should do any difference...

Comment: Did you refer to this [issue#92](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/issues/92)?

Comment: Yes, exactly that one

Comment: Related post - [IE11 JavaScript (Error: SCRIPT445) “Object doesn't support this action”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31765353/465053)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

http://caniuse.com/#search=file
[2] Some browser don't support the File constructor.

The only way you can get a File instance is through `input[type=file]`

instead of wrapping it around a try/catch why not just do this:

```
var blob = new Blob(['content'], { type: 'application/xml' });
saveAs(blob, fileName);
```

Comment: Hi, do you mean to use just Blob instead of File in anycase? ? I'm going to try it. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Hi again, it works, less code and more clean. Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

I have found a workaround that works on IE11.

This is the code:

```
try {
            var file = new File(['content'], fileName, { type: 'application/xml;charset=utf-8' });
            saveAs(file);
} catch (err) {
            var textFileAsBlob = new Blob(['content'], { type: 'application/xml' });
            window.navigator.msSaveBlob(textFileAsBlob, fileName);
}
```

I hope this will help somebody, working with IE11 consumes time for little thing like this.

Comment: this works great, but is there a way to specify the path to which to save the file to and maybe even to do it without the prompt?

Comment: Works great. Probably saved me at least a half a day. Thanks!