# TypeError: Object doesn't support this action in IE 11

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, cross-browser, internet-explorer-11

This is working fine in google chrome but getting error in internet explorer at below mentioned line in my code. Can anyone suggest what change do i need to make to it to work in IE.

`var file = new File([JSON.stringify($localStorage)], "somefile.txt", {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});`

Comment: Try including the following script <!--[if IE]>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

Comment: it is not working

Comment: Related post - [IE11 JavaScript (Error: SCRIPT445) “Object doesn't support this action”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31765353/465053)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Link to original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39329659/6369752)

To paraphrase the link, IE 11 does NOT support `new File()` constructor, so you'll have to use a blob instead. Here is a basic example:

```
var myArr = ["Hello", "World", "123", "Howdy"];
var b = new Blob([JSON.stringify(myArr)], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
window.navigator.msSaveBlob(b, "OutputFile.txt");
```

And now you should receive a download prompt.